# Boxplot chartjs make min and max dynamic by leaving some space on both side

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I am using chartjs v2.9 to draw a boxplot and my code looks like:

```js
function randomValues(count, min, max) {
  const delta = max - min;
  return Array.from({length: count}).map(() => Math.random() * delta + min);
}

const boxplotData = {
  // define label tree
  labels: ['Label 1', 'Label2'],
  datasets: [{
    label: 'Dataset 1',
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.5)',
    borderColor: 'red',
    borderWidth: 1,
    outlierColor: '#999999',
    padding: 10,
    itemRadius: 0,
    data: [
[0,0,150,150,150,150,150,150,150,150,150,150,150,150,150],
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
    ]
  }]
};
window.onload = () => {
  const ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
  window.myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'boxplot',
    data: boxplotData,
    options: {
      responsive: true,
      legend: {
        position: 'top',
      },
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Chart.js Box Plot Chart'
      },
/*       scales: {
          yAxes: [{
               ticks: {
                     min: -10,
                    max: 100,
                 }
            }]
      } */
    }
  });

};
```

```css
canvas {
      -moz-user-select: none;
      -webkit-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/chart.js@2.9.1"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@sgratzl/chartjs-chart-boxplot"></script>
<div id="container" style="width: 100%;">
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

Here, you can see on label 1 that there is an outliers exactly at `0` which makes it difficult to notice. I am willing to increase the min and max labels. For this case, I could increase min and max value using

```
 scales: {
          yAxes: [{
               ticks: {
                     min: -10,
                    max: 170,
                 }
            }]
      }
```

However, I want to make this dynamic. Is there any built-in function or any other methods so that I could dynamically add 1 further step, if it is on the edge.  In other words, I don't want the values to reach the min and max on the y-axis by keeping the same step size.

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fd6zx012/1/)

Update:

As you can see on chart there is step of 20, this means there is 0, 20, 40,..... Now what i am saying that if we need to increase / decrease the value I want to do it on the same ratio. Here, in case -20 not -10 and I want this to be dynamic instead of adding min - 20.

Answer (score 0):

While sending data from the server, you can send min and max value as well, and then use `suggestedMin` and `suggestedMax`

```
yAxes: [{
    ticks: {
        suggestedMin: receivedMinVal - 10,
        suggestedMax: receivedMaxVal + 10,
        }
    }
}]
```

where `received Val` refers to the value sent from the server. You can also use a js function to find the min and max values from the array. Suggested values will always increase the value by keeping the ratio of stepsize.

If you would like to learn more about this, read the documentation. You could read all about it at https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/linear.html#axis-range-settings